# Why can't one Mac use the other one's display as an "Extended or mirrored display" (whereas the other can in reverse)?

Tags: display, sonoma

Two MacBooks:

- (A) MacBook Pro 13 2019 (Sonoma 14.3)
- (B) MacBook Pro 14 2023 (Sonoma 14.3)

A can use B's display as an "Extended display". But, the other way around, B can't A's. Any idea why?

Here're `Displays` settings on A:
[image]
Here're `Displays` settings on B:
[image]

Both A and B have identical settings under `Displays > Advanced...`:
[image]